# Log variables being sent to control socket in Android

Tags: android, c

I'm having a hard time trying to get `/system/bin/raccoon` to log the variables being sent to it through the control socket. I can get it to log with any variables sent to the command line just fine but when I try to use an external app sending the variables to `/dev/socket/raccoon` I can't see them. What am I doing wrong? Below is the code. Thanks in advance

My logging code

```
FILE *filepntr = fopen("/sdcard/log.txt", "w");
    fprintf(filepntr, "\nThis line was for shits and giggles");
    fprintf(filepntr, "*argc:     %d\n", *argc );
    fprintf(filepntr, "*argv[0]:  %s\n", *argv[0] );

        if ( *argc == 1 ) {
                fprintf(filepntr, "No arguments were passed.\n" );
        } else {
                fprintf(filepntr,  "Arguments:\n" );

                for ( i = 1; i < *argc; ++i ) {
                        fprintf(filepntr, "  %d. %s\n", i, *argv[i] );
                }
        }
```

Below is the app code:

```
static int android_get_control_and_arguments(int *argc, char ***argv)
{
    static char *args[32];
    int control;
    int i;
    

    atexit(notify_death);

    if ((i = android_get_control_socket("racoon")) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    do_plog(LLV_DEBUG, "Waiting for control socket");
    if (listen(i, 1) == -1 || (control = accept(i, NULL, 0)) == -1) {
        do_plog(LLV_ERROR, "Cannot get control socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(i);
    fcntl(control, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
  
    
        
    args[0] = (*argv)[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 32; ++i) {
        unsigned char bytes[2];
        if (recv(control, &bytes[0], 1, 0) != 1 ||
                recv(control, &bytes[1], 1, 0) != 1) {
            do_plog(LLV_ERROR, "Cannot get argument length");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            int length = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1];
            int offset = 0;

            if (length == 0xFFFF) {
                break;
            }
            args[i] = malloc(length + 1);
            while (offset < length) {
                int n = recv(control, &args[i][offset], length - offset, 0);
                if (n > 0) {
                    offset += n;
                } else {
                    do_plog(LLV_ERROR, "Cannot get argument value");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            args[i][length] = 0;
        }
    }
    do_plog(LLV_DEBUG, "\n*Received %s Arguments");
  
    
    *argc = i;
    *argv = args;
    return control;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Check if the call to `fopen()` and `malloc()` succeeded.